# How to convert bash array to ADO pipeline variable array

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an array in bash that looks like:

`libs=test1 test2`

I would like to use the output of the bash script in a subsequent step in an ADO pipeline. How can I loop over this in ADO with pipeline variables like:

```
- ${{ each value in $(libs) }}:
   - script: echo $value
   - task: Npm@1
     inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: npm publish --ignore-scripts
      workingDir: 'dist/libs/$(value)'
      publishRegistry: 'useFeed'
      publishFeed: 'feed'
```

Comment: `libs=test1 test2` is not an array; `libs=test1` assigns the string `test1` to the variable `libs` while `test2` is treated as a command and, unless you have a command/alias/function named `test2`, should generate an error; `libs=(test1 test2)` , or `libs=('test1' 'test2')`, creates an array named `libs`

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I would like to use the libs variable array (test1 test2) to loop over in ADO pipeline, as mentioned above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot as `each` statement works only with `parameters` and not `variables` (as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)).

Moreover, `variables` are only `string` while `parameters` have different [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#parameter-data-types).